# Reflection with generic collections in O/R-mapping

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, orm

**Context**. I develop an O/R mapping in C# where I need to do "eager loading" of related tables on a collection. My database is a proprietary system, but in mock SQL this is what I do:

`select * from primarytable` (I get objects with ids 1, 2, 3, 4)

`select * from relatedtable where primaryid in (1, 2, 3, 4)`

The queries in this system are expensive so I can only afford one query per table, which leads to my problem. To provide context, there is a general class

`class Repository<T>`

Where the O/R mapping logic and database coupling lives. This is subclassed for each Model giving

`class MyModel : Model` (where every mapped database column is represented by a C# property)

`class MyModelRepository : Repository<MyModel>` (responsible for persisting MyModel instances)

Because I don't know in advance what columns/properties I need to access, there is a bit of reflection going on in `Repository<T>`. This has worked so far but now I have run into a wall.

**Problem**. The method I need to implement is this:

`// in Repository<T>
public void LoadMultiRelation(IEnumerable<T> resources, Type modelType, Type repoType)`

Where modelType is the type of the related model (subclassing Model) and repoType is the type of that model's repository (subclass of Repository). The child resources are represented by an `IEnumerable<T>` property on the parent Model class.

No matter how I do it I run into a conversion error of the type *Can't convert `IEnumerable<Model>` to `IEnumerable<MyModel>`*. The assignment is done with reflection like

`propertyOnParent.SetValue(theParent, collectionOfChildren)`

The static type of childrenCollection at this point is `IEnumerable<Model>` because I don't know what subclasses the user might define in his code. The code is supposed to work for completely general table schemas.

Sorry for the long question, I'd be happy to provide more information and am happy for any advice/pointers you might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, but here's the pattern I've used in the past:

```
public static class Utility
{   
  public static void SetProperty(PropertyInfo property, object target, IEnumerable value)
  {
    var valueType = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

    var genericConvertMethod = ConvertMethod.MakeGenericMethod(valueType);

    object correctlyTypedValue = genericConvertMethod.Invoke(null, new [] {value});

    property.SetValue(target, correctlyTypedValue);  
  }

  private static readonly MethodInfo ConvertMethod = typeof(Utility).GetMethod("Convert",BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.NonPublic);

  private static IEnumerable<T> Convert<T>(IEnumerable source)
  {
    // ToList is optional - depends on the behavior you want
    return source.OfType<T>().ToList();
  }
}
```

The type conversion rules are the same under reflection as in normal code. The reason they sometimes appear different is that when you set a value using reflection the setting code always uses the "real" type of the instance, rather than the type of the reference. So while you cannot write code like this:

```
IEnumerable<Base> a = new List<Derived>();
IEnumerable<Derived> b = a; // Cannot implicitly convert type!
```

you can write code like this:

```
IEnumerable<Base> a = new List<Derived>();
PropertyInfo prop = /* get a PropertyInfo which points to a static property of type IEnumerable<Derived> */;
prop.SetValue(null, a);
```

because the property setter sees `a` as what it really is, a `List<Derived>`. This can create the illusion that the reflection code is sometimes following a different set of rules than ordinary type conversion.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I used a solution similar to this. I have yet to see any patterns in what type conversions are allowed under reflection. The errors seem to come at random.

Comment: @jforberg, I've added some details which might make the errors seem less random.

Comment: Again thanks. What confused me is that I could assign the IEnumerable, but if I first did a .Where() on it then I could not assign (although the Where() passed without errors). In the end I just instantiated the IEnumerable using reflection also, and that worked. Seems I need to study this in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert `IEnumerable<MyClass>` to `IEnumerable<MyChildClass>` because in declaration of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) interface:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
```

the type parameter `T` is [covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx). It means, that you can convert `IEnumerable<MyChildClass>` to `IEnumerable<MyClass>` but not vice versa.
To get `IEnumerable<MyChildClass>` from `IEnumerable<MyClass>` you can use [`OfType<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) Linq extension method:

```
class MyClass { }
class MyChildClass : MyClass { }

//...
IEnumerable<MyClass> myClassList;
//...
IEnumerable<MyChildClass> myChildClassList = myClassList.OfType<MyChildClass>();
//...
```

So, you need to do something like above with reflection, as in example provided by Steve Ruble in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25179998/1805640).

Comment: Your explanation is correct, but your solution won't work because he doesn't know the type of the target property at compile time.

Comment: Thanks @nempobu4 but as stated, this is a general-purpose library so I can't make any assumptions about types.

Comment: @SteveRuble This is just an explanation about why OP has an error and what OP must do with reflection. It is difficult to fit this explanation in the comments.